# first item from user input not being included using append function

Tags: python, list, append, average, user-input

I'm trying to create a list of numbers from user input.

I tried to use 'append' to create the list so I am then able to calculate the average, but 'append' is not including the first number entered by the user.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

```
list_number = []  
number = float(input("Please enter any number (enter (-1) when done): "))



while number != -1:         
    number = float(input("Please enter any number (enter (-1) when done): "))
    list_number.append(number)
    if number == -1 : 
        print("You have exited the loop")
        break


print(list_number)
total_num = sum(list_number)
num_entries = len(list_number)
average = total_num / num_entries
print("Average: ", average)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you simply forgot to `list_number.append(number)` after the first `number = ...`. However, the while loop used here should be replaced with a "do while" to avoid repetition. To do this in Python, just `while True` and add a break statement if `number == -1` as you already have.

For example:

```py
list_number = []  

while True:
    number = float(input("Please enter any number (enter (-1) when done): "))
    if number == -1: 
        print("You have exited the loop")
        break
    else:
        list_number.append(number)

print(list_number)
total_num = sum(list_number)
num_entries = len(list_number)
average = total_num / num_entries
print("Average: ", average)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is that you are taking an input in line 2 but not appending it to your list.

You can either change line 2 to:

```
number = 0  #(anything but -1)
```

Or, you append the number to the list before the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

- You can achieve the result like this

```py
list_number = []

while 1:
    number = float(input("Please enter any number (enter (-1) when done): "))
    if number == -1:
        print("You have exited the loop")
        break
    list_number.append(number)

print(list_number)
total_num = sum(list_number)
num_entries = len(list_number)
average = total_num / num_entries
print("Average: ", average)
```

- `Output`

```py
python3 st.py
Please enter any number (enter (-1) when done): 12
Please enter any number (enter (-1) when done): 341
Please enter any number (enter (-1) when done): 2345
Please enter any number (enter (-1) when done): -1
You have exited the loop
[12.0, 341.0, 2345.0]
Average:  899.3333333333334
```

Answer (score 0):

list_number = []
number = 0

You used 2 entries, and your list was missing one of them, so you should set the value of number equal to 0, like this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a compact approach using assignment expressions (supported by python >= 3.8 only):

```
list_number = []
while (n := float(input("Enter a number (enter (-1) when done): "))) != -1:
    list_number.append(n)

print("You have exited the loop")
print("Average:", sum(list_number) / len(list_number))
```